# extract text between = and & using regex in presto sql

Tags: sql, regex, presto

I wanted to extract string between = and & using REGEXP_EXTRACT in Presto.

I did

```
select REGEXP_EXTRACT('blogId=abcde&logNo=222014685296','blogID=(.*)&');
```

but it returns NULL.

The result I want to get is 'abcde' here.

Could you help me out?

Thank you

Comment: `blogId` is not the same as `blogID`. Notice the uppercase `D`? Try: `select REGEXP_EXTRACT('blogId=abcde&logNo=222014685296','blogId=(.*)&', 1);`, where we extract value in group 1.

Comment: How did it work and what function you used? Will be helpful if you post it

Comment: @JvdV Thanks a lot. it worked well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is usually case sensitive and have `blogId` in your input string and `blogID` in your pattern.